# Как сохранить работу нодов "Geometry" и "Mapping" (Blender) для Unity?

Tags: unity3d, blender

Эти ноды позволяют сохранить размеры текстуры при любых размерах меша, но при экспорте такого меша в Unity результат будет совсем иным, ибо, насколько я знаю, ноды Blender не поддерживаются Unity. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ для сохранения результатов работы нодов "Geometry" и "Mapping"?

Comment: Unity не поддерживает? А кто поддерживает? Есть какой-то залитый цементом стандарт?

Comment: Не поддерживает?  Кто поддерживает? Какой-то залитый цементом стандарт?

Comment: Каким образом размер меша влияет на размер текстуры? Вы знаете, что такое uv развертка?

Comment: Имеется в виду, что текстура на меше растягивается при изменении размеров меша, чего можно избежать применив вышесказанные ноды, но а вопрос в том, как перенести работу этих нодов в Unity? Блин... хотя бы узнать, возможно ли это как-нибудь?

Answer (score 0):

Текстуры можно запечь, используя панель Bake:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. можно перенести активную текстуру с нестандартной разверткой или нестандартными процедурными текстурами на новое изображение.

Пока это поддерживается только Cycles (временно поменяйте рендер движок, если нужно запечь текстуры)